# Why does math.pow result in ValueError: math domain error?

Tags: python, exception, math, numerical-methods

Here is the code:

```
exp = 1.79
def calc(t):
    return pow(t - 1, exp)
```

The input values of `t` range from 0 to 1 (e.g. 0.04). This code throws a "math domain exception," but I'm not sure why.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What version of Python is this?  I tried `pow(-.6, 1.79)` in Python 3.2 and got a complex result.

Comment: @FreeMonicaCellio the built-in `pow` does that, as does `**` (with appropriate parentheses), but `math.pow` from the standard library reports an exception. Confusingly, both `pow`s describe themselves as `<built-in function pow>`, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `t` ranges from 0 to 1, then `t - 1` ranges from -1 to 0.  Negative numbers cannot be raised to a fractional power, neither by `pow` builtin nor `math.pow`.

Comment: pow and math.pow are the same no?

Comment: @Joan: No. `pow()` supports 3 arguments, for modulus, whereas `math.pow()` does not.

Comment: Thanks didn't know that. But when I do `from math import pow`, which pow is that?

Comment: That's the same as using `import math` and then `math.pow`, except that the name will now shadow the builtin `pow` in your namespace.  Note you can also use `x**y` for exponentiation.

Comment: Thanks wim. I didn't know pow was available without using math.

Answer (score 4):

Negative numbers raised to a fractional exponent do not result in real numbers. You will have to use [`cmath`](http://docs.python.org/library/cmath.html) if you insist on calculating and using them, but note that you will need some experience in complex numbers in order to make use of the result.

```
>>> cmath.exp(cmath.log(0.04 - 1) * 1.79)
(0.7344763337664206-0.5697182434534497j)
```

Comment: Python uses *j* instead of *i*? Heresy!

Answer (score 0):

```
exp = 1.79
def calc(t):
    return pow(t - 1, exp)

print calc(1.00) # t-1 is 0, there will be no error.
print calc(0.99) # t-1 is negative, will raise an error.
```